# Why does this corrupt my yaml file?

Tags: perl, yaml

When I run the below script I get a corrupt yaml file like so

```
--- 
1: 
  name1: abc
  name2: abc
---
me3: abc
---
```

**Question**

Can anyone see that I am doing wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use YAML::Syck;
use Fcntl ':flock', 'SEEK_SET';
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $acc;
my $acc_fh;

$acc->{1}{name1} = "abc";

unlink 'test.yaml';

# write initial
open F, '>', 'test.yaml';
print F YAML::Syck::Dump($acc);
close F;


($acc, $acc_fh) = read_yaml_with_lock('test.yaml');
$acc->{1}{name2} = "abc";
$acc->{1}{name3} = "abc";
write_yaml_with_lock($acc, $acc_fh);

($acc, $acc_fh) = read_yaml_with_lock('test.yaml');
delete $acc->{1}{name3};
write_yaml_with_lock($acc, $acc_fh);


sub read_yaml_with_lock {
    my ($file) = @_;

    open my $fh, '+<', $file or die $!;
    flock($fh, LOCK_EX) or die $!;

    my $obj = YAML::Syck::LoadFile($fh); # this dies on failure
    return ($obj, $fh);
}

sub write_yaml_with_lock {
    my ($obj, $fh) = @_;

    my $yaml = YAML::Syck::Dump($obj);
    $YAML::Syck::ImplicitUnicode = 1;
    seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;   # seek back to the beginning of file

    print $fh $yaml . "---\n";
    close $fh;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write to the same file twice. During the second time the YAML code you're writing is shorter than the first time because you delete that hash key inbetween the calls. However, you neither `unlink` the file after the first time nor do you `truncate` it after writing to it the second time. So what you see as corruption is the part of the file that has been written the first time but that hasn't been overwritten the second time.

Comment: I see. I was just under the impression that, the file size would adapt. How would you make proper `truncate`?

Comment: Two possibilities: truncate to 0 and write afterwards (no need to seek in that situation) or seek, write, and truncate to the current file position afterwards.

Comment: So you mean `truncate($fh, tell $fh)`?

Comment: For case 2? Pretty much, yes.

Answer (score 3):

The `"me3"` part is what is left of `"  name3"`, which gets partially overwritten by `"---\n"` (4 characters). When you write the first time, you have more data. Then you rewind the file handle position and write a shorter data, which does not overwrite all of the old.

I think your solution "should" be to skip this passing a file handle around and rewinding it and instead use the appropriate `open` for each subroutine. E.g.:

```
sub read_yaml {
    my $file = shift;
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
    ...
    close $fh;
}

sub write_yaml {
    my ($file, $obj) = @_;
    open my $fh, '>', $file or die $!;
    ...
    close $fh;
}
```

Keeping the file handle open in between operations not really that useful or efficient, and it introduces some difficulties.

Comment: Is the solution to replace `seek $fh, 0, SEEK_SET;` with `truncate($fh, 0);`?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting When you play around with `+<` mode `seek` etc, you are making things more difficult for yourself. You do not save (much) time compared to closing the file and reopening it. So my advice would be to reopen the file in truncate mode.

Comment: I am a little lost here. How do I open a file in truncate mode?

Comment: That's how you opened the file in your code, using the `'>'` mode. It truncates (deletes content) the file before opening for writing.

Comment: But I don't close the file after reading it. I only `close` in the write function.

Comment: I know you didn't, that's why you are having troubles.